# How to check for immutability the simulated signal after edge coming in SystemVerilog?

Tags: fpga, system-verilog, edge

Suppose that we have some module (which simulates FPGA external environment) with an input line (from a FPGA). When an edge (rising/falling) comes from this line the module must test that the logic state is immutabe for N nanoseconds after the edge comes.

The primitive solution is creating a fast looping loop that checks the line stage on each iteration. But I think the SystemVerilog sintax provides more handy solution. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fork/join_any`

```
always begin
    @(input_line) // wait for any edge rising or falling
    fork
        #(N * 1ns);
        @(input_line) $error("Caught an error");
    join_any
    disable fork; // kills whichever process did not finish
  end
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to catch a sub-nanosecond impulse? I mean this method baiscaly similar to fast loop and differs more in syntax. Is it possible to catch infinitesimal impulse without any loop-like structure (just like the "always @(xxx)" can)?

Comment: If by _infinitesimal impulse_ you mean a glitch having a width less than the discrete width of simulation time precision, the answer is no, you cannot catch that in simulation. The `#(expression);` statement has to be equal or grater than the time precision.